# Want to Save visual studio project ON CD?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014

I have made phonebook project on visual studio and used sql server management studio for database and want to save that project on CD please tell me how can I move it to CD?

Comment: Do you mean CD as in Compact Disc?

Comment: Burn the solution folder + mdf files from the DB to disc?

Comment: Is database you are using support running from read-only media? (Or if you are asking how to copy files to CD you should be asking on SuperUser.com)

Comment: I don't know it support running from read-only media or not.I just want that my project save on CD and when I run that CD on another pc it will show my values saved on database in output.

Comment: Having it run on another machine from the CD is a different question entirely; that all depends on how you wrote the program in the first place

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic since it doesn't have anything to do with programming, it is about saving media to a CD

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Visual Studio, I assume you're using Windows.  [These are the official Microsoft instructions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/burn-a-cd-or-dvd)

Basically:

1. Put a blank disc in the burner
2. When the dialog window comes up, click "Burn files to disc"
3. Copy the files to the window that appears
4. Click 'Burn to disc'

Comment: when I run that CD on another computer does it will show data that is stored on my phonebook stored in my database?

Comment: @dove  - if you're using MS SQL Server how are accessing the database stored on the CD?   The database would have to be "Attached" to SQL Server DB engine.

Comment: You...  Shouldn't do that.  CDs are read-only, so you wouldn't be able to make changes to the data.